# Method Chooser in Intellij IDEA plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm developing plugin for IDEA. It need to select public abstract methods with no parameters, and allow user to choose subset of them. I found MemberChooser dialog, but cannot see similar thing for methods.

So if I have List<PsiMethod> how to show dialog for choosing subset of them?

Comment: Is it not possible to use `MemberChooser.selectElements` with your list? (create a `PsiMethodMember` from each `PsiMethod`, if necessary ?)

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve! It's solution!

Comment: btw, is there any good resources or books about building plugins for idea? documentation on jetbrains site looks partly outdated, partly quite difficult to find answers.

Comment: Ok, I wrote it as an answer, would you mind to accept it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MemberChooser.selectElements` with your list.

That is, if you create a `PsiMethodMember` from each `PsiMethod`.